# periodic function is constant

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Let $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a function with intermediate value property, such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \infty$. Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a periodic function such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(g(x))$ exists, then $f$ is constant.

This is what I have tried:
As $g$ is a function with IVP such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \infty$, there exists an interval $[a, \infty) \subset Im(g)$. Let $x_0$ be a real number and let $T>0$ be one of the periods of $f$, and define $x_n=x_0+ nT$. Then, because $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n =\infty$, there exists a positive integer $n_0$ such that $x_n \in Im(g)$ for all $n \ge n_0$. Therefore there exists a sequence $(y_n)_{n\ge1}$ such that $g(y_n)=x_n$ for all $n\ge n_0$. Then $f(g(y_n))=f(x_0)$ for all $n \ge n_0$. If I can get that $(y_n)_{n\ge1}$ is unbounded I would be done, because then $f(x_0)=l$, and since $x_0$ was chosen arbitrarily, $f$ would be constant. I can't find a reason why or why not this is not true. I would be glad to receive some help!

Answer (score 3):

Let $a$ denote the period of $f.$  Denote $A=f([0,a]).$
Fix an arbitrary $x_0.$ As $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty,$  there exists $x_1>x_0$ such that $g(x_1)\ge g(x_0)+a.$
By the intermediate value property the function $g:[x_0,x_1]\to \mathbb{R}$ admits all the values of in the interval $[g(x_0), g(x_0)+a].$ Therefore the function $f(g(x))$ for $x\ge x_0$ admits all the values in $A.$ The limit exists if and only if $A$ consists of just one point. Therefore the function $f$ is constant.

Comment: Could you reformulate: As $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \infty$, there exists $x_1>x_0$ such that $g(x_1)\ge g(x_0)+a.$

Comment: Re-edited, thanks.

Comment: Am I missing something? The last part doesn't imply that $A$ consists of one element. $f(g(x))$ can take all values of $A$ except one and take the last for an infinite amount of terms.  For example, if $A$ is an open interval on one end and then closed on another.

Comment: For any $x_0$ the function $f(g(x))$ takes all the values of $A$ in the interval $[x_0,\infty).$ In particular $m=\min A$ and $M=\max A$ are taken in $[x_0, \infty).$ If the limit of $f(g(x))$ existed and $M>m,$ then for $x_0$ large enough we would  have $|f(x)-f(x')|< M-m$  for all  $x,x'\ge x_0.$ This gives a contradiction.

Comment: So basically, because this happens for every $x_0$, then for all sufficiently large $x$, $A$ is included in $f(g([x, \infty)))$ which is included in $(l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon)$, where $l$ is the limit. And if we take the limit of $\epsilon$ to $0$ we get that $A={l}$.

Comment: Yes. But I prefer to use the Cauchy condition for existence of the limit. The diameter of the values of $f(g(x))$ tends to $0$ at infinity and is equal $M-m.$ Hence $M=m.$

Comment: I have but one more question. In my attempt in the original post, is it true that $(y_n)_{n\ge1}$ is unbounded?

Comment: Let $g(x)=x^{-1}\sin (x^{-1})$ for $x<0$ and $g(x)=x$ for $x\ge 0.$ Then $g(x)$ satisfies IMV. Moreover $g((-1,0))=\mathbb{R},$ hence $y_n$ can be chosen from $(-1,0).$